# Rails model not syncing properly with database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails model called `Merchant` with attributes `name` and `id`. I am having an issue where rails and my database disagree on a certain Merchant's name.

This is what's happening from rails:

```
1.9.2p320 :001 > Merchant.where(:id=>550).count 
=> 1 
1.9.2p320 :002 > Merchant.where(:id=>550).first.name
=> nil
```

And this is what's happening from mysql:

```
mysql> SELECT name FROM merchants WHERE id=550;
+----------+
| name     |
+----------+
| Testname |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

According to `FlyersAdmin::Application.config.database_configuration[::Rails.env]` the database being used by rails in my first code window is the same as that being used by mysql in the second window. Why the merchant's name is `nil` instead of "Testname" is what I'm stumped on.

Worth noting is that recently I updated the database they're both using with new data, is it possible that this is causing the discrepancy? Maybe rails caches data and so hasn't looked at the updated database yet? I'm stumped, any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
Here's another clue to add to the mystery: Running `Merchant.where(:name => nil)` returns the empty list! Why isn't it picking the Merchant with id 550?

Comment: Consider giving us the whole model, and the output when fetching the whole record.

Comment: The reason I don't want to do that is because the whole record contains sensitive data, such as FTP user/pass. I can tell you that the rails model and the database agree on several fields that are not name.

Answer (score 0):

What should be the output of this `Merchant.where(:id=>550).first.name`?. It is possible you created a Merchant but you just did not define a name, so it got the default value `nil`

Comment: Merchant.where(:id=>550).first should be the merchant model associated with the row where id=550 in the merchants table. The question asks why one of these has a name and the other does not

Answer (score 0):

Why you do .first when you select one record anyway?

```
Merchant.find(550).name
```

should give you your record.

Try

```
Merchant.first.name
```

to get the first record of the model.

Comment: `Merchant.where(:id=>550)` returns a list of all Merchants that match the condition `:id=>550` (hence why I included .count, to show only one matched). The first element of that list is the relevant merchant.

Comment: @notarobot You have a model where your identifier id is not unique??? You should consider refactor your model. Whe you create a new model in RoR the default column for your primary index is 'id'.

Comment: OK, what happens if you do Merchant.where('id = 550').first ?

Comment: Changed my answer to .find(550), this dont give your a collection, just one record.

Comment: `1.9.2p320 :002 > Merchant.find(550) == Merchant.where(:id => 550).first
    => true`. They are equivalent statements

Comment: Ofc it is the same, but why do it complicated :)? Anyway, if you get a record in both ways what is the content in your rails console? Your sample said that .name is nil, so show us your model.

Comment: Okay okay, fair enough! I'd rather not show the whole model as some sensitive data is contained within, but I can tell you that the model and the record do agree on several fields.

Comment: No problem. What happens if you call Merchant.find(550). Is this nil or not? If not, your console shows the data returned (all columns). Maybe you have a method overload of name, created a `def name` in your model.

Comment: Merchant.find(550) is decidedly non-nil. It agrees with many other columns in the row, in fact name is the only one I can find where they disagree. I just checked and there's no `def name` in the model but that would have explained it. drats!

Comment: is `.name` always nil or just for this record? Try create a def name and inside do a `self.name` as return. I also checked http://latheesh.com/2010/02/02/rails-reserved-words/ if `name` is reserved, it is not.

Comment: I did what you said and got a "stack level too deep error" - `self.name` calls Merchant#name lol. I changed the name of the function to merch_name, but the result is still `1.9.2p320 :001 > Merchant.find(550).merch_name
 => nil `

Comment: Here's something strange though: `Merchant.where(:name => nil)` returns the empty list. What??